# Which women's fashion clothes can I manufacture for my clothing brand?

Tags: business, awrah, fashion-design

I started a western clothing brand but I am confused about which women's clothes can I sell? Like I can sell straight or flared jeans as they don't expose the awrah. What else can I make?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can make whatever ypu want even if it revels because the cloths maybe be used with her mehram or infront of other women.